fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab.syntaxjuggler.com/dev/project.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
When creating a pipeline and running it for any project, the Forbbiden error occurs, whether the repository is open or not does not affect this error.
Pipeline
stages:
  - build
  - step1
  - step2

variables:
  REGISTRY: "https://index.docker.io/v1/"
  VERSION:
    value: ""
    description: "Введите tag (версию) контейнера. Пример: v0.0.1"

.build: &build_def
  stage: build
  image:
    name: gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:v1.11.0-debug
    entrypoint: [""]
  before_script:
    - |
      if [ -z $VERSION ]; then
        echo "Please select a container version"
        exit 1 
      fi
    - echo ${PROJECT_DIR}
    - echo ${CONTAINER_NAME}
    - echo "{\"auths\":{\"${REGISTRY}\":{\"auth\":\"$(printf "%s:%s" "${REGISTRY_USER}" "${REGISTRY_PASSWORD}" | base64 | tr -d '\n')\"}}}" > /kaniko/.docker/config.json
  script:
    - echo "Build container..."
    - /kaniko/executor 
      --context $PROJECT_DIR 
      --dockerfile $PROJECT_DIR/Dockerfile 
      --destination ${CONTAINER_NAME}
  tags:
    - stage
  when: manual
  only:
    - web

application1: 
  <<: *build_def
  variables:
    CONTAINER_NAME: bigkaa/gitlab-application1:${VERSION}
    PROJECT_DIR: ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/application1

application2: 
  <<: *build_def
  variables:
    CONTAINER_NAME: bigkaa/gitlab-application2:${VERSION}
    PROJECT_DIR: ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/application2

step1:
  stage: step1 
  cache:
    key: test-cache
    paths:
      - some_path/
  script:
    - mkdir some_path
    - echo "Hello from step1" > some_path/hello.txt 
  tags:
    - stage
  when: manual
  only:
    - web

step2:
  stage: step2 
  cache:
    key: test-cache
    paths:
      - some_path/
  script:
    - cat some_path/hello.txt
  tags:
    - stage
  when: manual
  only:
    - web

Runners configuration
imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
revisionHistoryLimit: 3
gitlabUrl: https://gitlab.syntaxjuggler.com/
terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 3600
# Количество раннеров
concurrent: 5
checkInterval: 30
logLevel: info
logFormat: json
sessionServer:
  enabled: false
rbac:
  create: true
  rules:
  - resources: ["pods", "secrets", "configmaps"]
    verbs: ["get", "list", "watch", "create", "patch", "delete", "update"]
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["pods/exec", "pods/attach"]
    verbs: ["create", "patch", "delete"]
  clusterWideAccess: true
  podSecurityPolicy:
    enabled: false
    resourceNames:
    - gitlab-runner
metrics:
  enabled: true
  portName: metrics
  port: 9252
  serviceMonitor:
    enabled: false
service:
  enabled: true
runners:
  config: |
    # log_level = "debug"
    [[runners]]
      output_limit = 10000
      [runners.kubernetes]
        image = "ubuntu:22.04"
        # helper_image = "if use custom helper"
      [runners.cache]
        Type = "s3"
        Path = "runner"
        Shared = true
        [runners.cache.s3]
          ServerAddress = "gitlab-minio.gitlab.svc.cluster.local:9000"
          BucketName = "runner-cache"
          BucketLocation = "nbg1"
          Insecure = false
          AuthenticationType = "access-key"
  cache:
    secretName: gitlab-runner
  executor: kubernetes
  secret: gitlab-runner
securityContext:
  runAsUser: 100
  # runAsGroup: 65533
  fsGroup: 65533
  # supplementalGroups: [65533]
resources:
  limits:
    memory: 256Mi
    cpu: 200m
  requests:
    memory: 128Mi
    cpu: 100m

An error that occurs when starting the runner
Running with gitlab-runner 17.2.1 (9882d9c7)
  on gitlab-runner-848474899d-2hxfg ZCLbfgpyE, system ID: r_5D9FZv9JrMxM
Preparing the "kubernetes" executor
00:00
Using Kubernetes namespace: gitlab
Using Kubernetes executor with image ubuntu:22.04 ...
Using attach strategy to execute scripts...
Preparing environment
00:04
Using FF_USE_POD_ACTIVE_DEADLINE_SECONDS, the Pod activeDeadlineSeconds will be set to the job timeout: 1h0m0s...
Waiting for pod gitlab/runner-zclbfgpye-project-2-concurrent-0-aquc04fn to be running, status is Pending
Running on runner-zclbfgpye-project-2-concurrent-0-aquc04fn via gitlab-runner-848474899d-2hxfg...
Getting source from Git repository
00:00
Fetching changes with git depth set to 20...
Initialized empty Git repository in /builds/root/test2/.git/
Created fresh repository.
fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab.syntaxjuggler.com/root/test2.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: command terminated with exit code 1

It seems to me that the problem is not in the pipeline, but I’ll attach it anyway, the error occurs even before its configuration begins at the moment of copying the repository source code.
I tried to check the operation of the pipeline on different runners and this also did not give anything. I tried turning restrictions on and off in the "Job token permissions" setting and that didn't help either.

Is the runner placed behind a proxy?

@MichaelKotzjan It is hosted on the same Kubernetes cluster as Gitlab but accesses a domain that uses a proxy

sounds to me like this could be the problem. Are you able to connect to an instance of the cluster manually to run some tests? It could help you to figure out exactly what config is needed für the pipeline

The problem was with the proxy server over the domain that I was using with Gitlab, disabling it and getting a valid certificate helped. It seems to me that this happened due to a bad Server -> Cloudflare certificate, but, unfortunately, I can’t check this yet.
UPD: Even with valid certificates Server -> Cloudflare I get this error, the problem is with the proxy
